# Are all of the following correct? "She enjoys/keeps/has good health."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, verbs

> a. She enjoys good health.

> b. She keeps good health.

> c. She has good health.

In academic discourse we usually read 'enjoy good health', does it mean other expressions are wrong or have other sense than 'enjoy good health'?

Comment: Not so much "academic discourse" - to ***enjoy good health*** is [*a rather dated poetic **Victorian** usage*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+enjoys+good+health%2CHe+has+good+health%2CHe+is+healthy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) Natural phrasing, as per that linked NGram, is simply ***She is healthy***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three sentences are similar in meaning, as they all convey that the subject (she) is in a state of good health. However, there are subtle differences in emphasis and connotation among the three sentences:

"She enjoys good health" suggests that the subject experiences or benefits from a state of good health. The verb "enjoys" implies a positive experience, focusing on the pleasure or satisfaction that comes from being in good health.

"She keeps good health" implies that the subject actively maintains her good health through habits or lifestyle choices. The verb "keeps" suggests ongoing effort or attention to staying in good health.

"She has good health" is a more neutral statement of fact, simply indicating that the subject is in good health.

And as FumbleFingers stated, "to enjoy good health" is simply a more poetic way of implying being healthy. Thus, you can also simply go with "She is healthy".

Comment: Or "She is in good health".

Comment: *She keeps good health*, is missing a preposition.  It is not idiomatic as written.  Or is this a BrE usage?  Does anyone still talk like this?